# Implement pointer style BST in Java?

Tags: java, pointers, reference, binary-search-tree, traversal

Now ,I clearly understand that Java references are 'Pass by value '

and that

```
Ref r=null;
....
method m1(Ref r)
{
r=r2;
..
}

..//r remains null
```

But i just wrote a  C pointer style BST program in Java with 3 in,post,pre order traversals and other methods, is there any way by which i can now tweak it by modifying just a few lines, none i could think of...

Please suggest some way to get this working

*Is there any language construct in Java that allows us to treat java references similar to C pointers?*

**Node.java**

```
public class Node{


private int key;
private Node left;
private Node right;

Node(int key)
{
    this.key=key;
    left=null;
    right=null;//redundant as java by default sets to null

}

public int getKey()
{
    return key;
}

public void setKey(int value)
{
    key=value;
}


public Node getLeft()
{
    return left;
}
public  void setLeft(Node left)
{
    this.left=left;
}



public Node  getRight()
{
    return right;
}
public  void setRight(Node right)
{
    this.right=right;
}




}//class Node ends
```

**BST.java**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class BST {

    private Node root;

    BST()
    {
        root=null;
    }

    public void insert(int value,Node n)
    {
        if(n==null)//found place to enter ,so enter the value there
        {   System.out.println("\nInserting "+value);
            n=new Node(value);
            //n.setKey(value);
        }

        else//need to traverse accordingy
        {
            if(value<n.getKey())//go left
            {
                insert(value,n.getLeft());
                System.out.println("Left of");
            }

            else if (value>n.getKey())//go right
            {
                insert(value,n.getRight());

            }
            else//its a duplicate
            {
                System.out.println("duplicate");
            }


        }

    }

    void preorder(Node n)
    {   System.out.println("Inside Preorder");

        if(n!=null)
        {   System.out.println("Traversing Inorder");
            System.out.println(" "+n.getKey());
            preorder(n.getLeft());
            preorder(n.getRight());
        }
    }

    void postorder(Node n)
    {

        if(n!=null)
        {
            postorder(n.getLeft());
            postorder(n.getRight());
            System.out.println(" "+n.getKey());
        }
    }



    void inorder(Node n)
    {

        if(n!=null)
        {
            inorder(n.getLeft());
            System.out.println(" "+n.getKey());
            inorder(n.getRight());
        }
    }

public Node getroot()
{
    return root;
}


public static void main(String[] args)
{
BST bst=new BST();
int ch=0;

Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

while(true)
{
    System.out.println("Enter choice 1:Insert ,2:Pre Order,3:PostOrder,4:Inorder 0:Exit");
    ch=sc.nextInt();

    switch(ch)
    {

    case 1:
    System.out.println("\nENter the number of elements");

    int n=sc.nextInt();
    int[] temp=new int[n];

    System.out.println("Enter elements to insert");

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        temp[i]=sc.nextInt();
    }


    for(int ele:temp)
    {
    bst.insert(ele,bst.getroot());
    }
    //done inserting all elements
    break;

    case 2:
    System.out.println("PreOrder traversal is \n");
    bst.preorder(bst.getroot());
    break;

    case 3:
    System.out.println("PostOrder traversal is \n");
    bst.postorder(bst.getroot());
    break;

    case 4:
    System.out.println("InOrder traversal is \n");
    bst.inorder(bst.getroot());
    break;


    case 0:
    System.out.println("Exiting");
    System.exit(0);
    break;

    default:
    System.out.println("Enter valid choice");
    }//switch ends
}//loop ends

}// main ends
}//class BST ends
```

Comment: I think i mentioned it , whats the easiest way to change the code without rewriting the entire thing,cause the insert method does not add the new node ,as root still is null after the method exits

Comment: Why is that surprising? You've never modified `root` (that I can see); if you want it to be set to the new `node`, why don't you say `root = node` at some point in the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know if I understand correctly, but the problem seems to be in the insert method (int value, Node n), where n variable receives an instance in this method.

If the problem is really that you could return the instance rather than assign the variable inside the method, that way, you could use the returned value and then to set the variable you passed as a parameter. Would look something like:

```
  public Node insert(int value,Node n){
    if(n==null){
        return new Node(value);
    }else{
        if(value<n.getKey()){
            Node newNode = insert(value,n.getLeft());
            if(n.getLeft()==null){
              n.setLeft(newNode);
            }
            return newNode;
        }else if (value>n.getKey()){
            Node newNode = insert(value,n.getRight());
            if(n.getRight()==null){
              n.setRight(newNode);
            }
            return newNode;
        }else{
            System.out.println("duplicate");
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Another point I would make is that there are already BST implementations in Java, unless you are using this model to train only suggest you use the implementations that already exist.

Comment: Thanks thats my issue , and yes I'm using it just to train, could you please make those changes to the code and post back as an answer..it'll be helpful

Comment: Hi @Droid Ics, You could understand my suggestion? Corresponded to what you needed?

Comment: thanks i made the changes and changed the insert method to return a value , now it works , i did it a little different though